# Resources to understand the bootstrap

Tags: references, resampling

I am looking for any recommendations on resources to learn more about bootstrapping from a theoretical and rigorous perspective in terms of bounds/guarantees/etc. Any books or papers would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean besides the recommendations at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/128839 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6538?

Comment: Yep, besides those. I think I am more interested in learning how it applies to statistical learning theory - especially to something like random forests and when your draws may not be i.i.d

Comment: Thank you -- please include that in your question so that the answers here don't duplicate the answers in the other threads.

Answer (score 1):

Bradley Efron is the statistician that introduced the bootstrap sampling technique. His original paper is [Bootstrap Methods: Another Look at the Jacknife](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-7/issue-1/Bootstrap-Methods-Another-Look-at-the-Jackknife/10.1214/aos/1176344552.full).

Efron also released [Computer Age Statistical Inference](https://hastie.su.domains/CASI/) with Trevor Hastie in 2016 which has a chapter on the Jackknife and the Bootstrap. The book is available for download on the linked site above.

Larry Wasserman's *All of Statistics: A Concise Course in Statistical Inference* has a great chapter on the bootstrap as well but I don't believe this book has been made freely available.